# Row Reduction of a matrix

Tags: matrices

Let us consider the following matrix $$M= \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
             1 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 5 \\
             1 & 1 & 2 & 6 & 10 \\
             1 & 2 & 5 & 2 & 7 \\
                \end{array} } \right]$$

I was able to reduce the above matrix to a row echelon matrix:

$$M'=\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
             1 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 3 \\
             0 & 1 & 3 & 0 & 1 \\
             0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
                \end{array} } \right]$$

But I don't know how to express M' as a multiplication by a sequence $E_1,...,E_k$ of elementary matrices: $$M'=E_k...E_2E_1M$$

Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you tell us the sequence of $k$ row operations that you used to reduce $M$ to $M'$?

Comment: @Adriano 
1) $R_2 \rightarrow R_2 - R_1$
2) $R_3 \rightarrow R_3-R_1$
3) $ R_2 \leftrightarrow R_3$
4) $R_1 \rightarrow R_1- R_2$
5) $ R_3 \rightarrow \frac{1}{5} R_3$
6) $R_2 \rightarrow R_2 - R_3$

Comment: Given that each row operation can be represented by a left-product with an invertible matrix $E$, can you find $E$ for the 3 types of row operation?

Comment: @JonathanY. That is my question actually. Could you explain to me how to express each type of row operation as a elementary matrix ?

As in: 1) Linear combination $\Leftrightarrow$ elementary matrix
2) Multiplying a row by a scalar $\Leftrightarrow$ elementary matrix
3) Interchanging two rows $\Leftrightarrow$ elementary matrix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$M'=E_k...E_2E_1M$

From the row operations you provided, we arrive at:

$\begin{bmatrix} 1& 0& 0 \\0& 1& -1 \\ 0& 0& 1  \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1& 0& 0 \\ 0& 1& 0 \\ 0& 0& 1/5  \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 1& -1& 0 \\ 0& 1& 0 \\ 0& 0& 1 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 1& 0& 0 \\ 0& 0& 1 \\ 0&1& 0 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 1& 0& 0 \\ 0& 1& 0 \\ -1& 0& 1 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 1& 0& 0 \\ -1& 1& 0 \\ 0& 0& 1 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 5 \\ 1 & 1 & 2 & 6 & 10 \\ 1 & 2 & 5 & 2 & 7 \\ \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 3 \\0 & 1 & 3 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: $\ddot\smile$ thanks!

Comment: No, actually, [it was deleted](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/475811/9003) because of the flags. I've flagged for moderator attention. Perhaps you can flag it for mod attention, too :-(

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** To remember how to express each type of row operation as an elementary matrix, simply perform that row operation on the identity matrix. Thus, for example, the first elementary matrix $E_1$ corresponding to your first row operation (adding $(-1) \cdot R_1$ to $R_2$) would be:
$$
E_1 = \begin{bmatrix}
 1 & 0 & 0 \\
-1 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

Can you see how this matrix was obtained? Can you see why its size is $3 \times 3$, and not $5 \times 5$?

Comment: Thank you. I understand now. Have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

If we take $A\in\mathbb{F}^{n\times m}$ and $x\in\mathbb{F}^n$, then $x^TA\in\mathbb{F}^m$ is a linear combination of $A$'s rows with coefficients $x_1,x_2\ldots,x_n$. It follows that for $E\in\mathbb{F}^{n\times n}$, each row of $EA$ is a linear combination of $A$'s rows with coefficients given by the corresponding row of $E$. This should be helpful in constructing the different types of elementary matrices.